# Detect scroll occurrence in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6

I wrote this scroll area in pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QSlider, QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QScrollArea,QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.scroll = QScrollArea()          
    self.widget = QWidget()            
    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()       

    for i in range(1,50):
        object = QLabel("TextLabel")
        self.vbox.addWidget(object)

    self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

    #Scroll Area Properties
    self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

    self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

    self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
    self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
    self.show()

    return

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I want is:

1.When you scroll up -> print('scroll up occurred ')
2.When you scroll down -> print('scroll down occurred ')
3.When the scroll reaches the end of the scroll area -> print('The scroll has reached the end')
4.When scroll down handle is clicked -> print('down handle is triggered')
5.When scroll up handle is clicked -> print('up handle is triggered')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QSlider, QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        for i in range(1, 50):
            object = QLabel("TextLabel")
            self.vbox.addWidget(object)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        # Scroll Area Properties
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()

        # Connect signals to slots
        self.position = self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().actionTriggered.connect(self.on_scroll)
        self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.scrolled)
        return

    def on_scroll(self, action):
        
        # In case you scroll using the mouse wheel or clicking the bar.
        if(self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition() > self.position):
            print('scroll down occurred ')
            self.position = self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        if(self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition() < self.position):
            print('scroll up occurred ')
            self.position = self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        
        # SliderSingleStepAdd for when you click the arrow up.
        # SliderPageStepAdd for when you click the bar up.    
        if (action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderSingleStepAdd) or (action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderPageStepAdd):
            print('scroll down occurred ')
        # SliderSingleStepSub for when you click the arrow down.
        # SliderPageStepSub for when you click the bar down.
        if (action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderSingleStepSub) or (action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderPageStepSub):
            print('scroll up occurred ')

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525448/python-pyqt-scrollbar-in-the-end-position-event
    def scrolled(self, value):
        if value == self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().maximum():
            print ('reached max') # that will be the bottom/right end
        if value == self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().minimum():
            print ('reached min') # top/left end

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You don't need all this. Just connect to `actionTriggered` and compare the current `value()` with `sliderPostion()` to detect up/down, and compare `sliderPosition()` with `maximum()` and `minimum()` to detect max/min. There's no need to check the action at all.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have tried to do that but if you clicked on the scroll bar (the greyest part) and If I don't check the last position and the new one it doesn't recognise.

Comment: It works fine for me (on Linux). Using your example, if I put `print(action)` at the top of `on_scroll`, it shows `3` or `4` when the grey section is clicked. The `sliderPosition` will always be different from the `value` if the slider isn't at min/max. This is how [actionTriggered](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#actionTriggered) is documented to work, so if you see something different on your system, that would be a bug.